# JQuery поиск обработчика события объекта

Tags: jquery, dom, события

Мне нужно найти, какие обработчики событий записаны на объекте.

Например:

```
$("#el").click(function() {...});
$("#el").mouseover(function() {...});
```

На `$("#el")` записаны события *click* и *mouseover*.

Есть ли функция, чтобы узнать это, и можно ли выполнить итерацию по обработчикам событий?

Если это невозможно в объекте jQuery с помощью правильных методов, возможно ли это для обычного объекта DOM?

<sup>Переведено с: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/</sup>

Comment: Ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Начиная с jQuery 1.8, информация о событиях больше не доступна из «public API» для данных. Прочтите [это сообщение в блоге jQuery](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/). Теперь, для того чтобы узнать список событий записанных на объекте, нужно использовать это:

```
jQuery._data( elem, "events" );
```

*elem* должен быть элементом HTML, а не объектом jQuery или селектором.

Обратите внимание, что это внутренняя, «частная» структура, и ее не следует изменять. Используйте это только для целей отладки.

В старых версиях jQuery вам может потребоваться использовать старый метод:

```
jQuery( elem ).data( "events" );
```

---

*Пример:*

```js
$('#el').click(function() {
  $(this).text('Нажали!');
})

$('#el').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).text('Поводили мышкой!');
});

// Получаем события

var elem = $('#el').get(0);

console.log( $._data(elem, "events") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="el">Текст</div>
```